# URL changes but view does not change

Tags: angularjs

This is how I define the href tag.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="chapter in chapters" ng-href="#/tab/kurals">
    {{chapter}}
</ion-item>
```

When I click on the item, the url of the browser changes to /tab/kurals, but there is no change in the view. Still the old view is shown. For ionic tabs, I have an abstract route. All other links works fine.

Below is how I defined my routes.

```
$stateProvider.state('tab.kural', {
    url: '/kurals',
    views: {
        'tab-kural': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-kural.html',
            controller: 'KuralCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

I have also tried this.

```
$stateProvider.state('tab.kural', {
    url: '/kurals',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-kural.html',
    controller: 'KuralCtrl'
});
```

There are no errors in the console.

What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Have you got a 'parent' state? e.g. `$stateProvider.state('tab', { url: '/tabs', //etc. }` ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in question, I have the abstract state /tabs

Comment: Is this because of a typo? You have `'/tabs'` in your parent state but `ng-href="#/tab/kurals"` in html. Pardon me, I'm just thiking out loud.

Comment: @manu29.d Its a valid thought. I have double checked for spelling mistakes.. There was none :(

Comment: @Purus, did you define `url: "/tab"` on the parent state?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-href="#/tab/kurals"` will not gonna match  `url: '/kurals'` you can change any of then for it like `url:'/tabs/kurals'` or `ng-href="#/kurals"`. Else best way it to u use ui-serf="tab.kural".

I am assuming your child view name is "tab-kural".

Comment: There is an abstract route called /tabs and its required to be used as /tabs/kurals. All other links work fine.

Comment: I support the opinion that you should be using `ui-sref` in your views.

Comment: ui-sref also does not work for this particular state.. no errors in this case too.