# Ionic UI Router issue: 2nd level state views not loading

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I can't wrap my head around this issue I've been experiencing, or perhaps I'm missing some crucial point here. I jotted down [this sample app](http://play.ionic.io/app/575669414876) on ionic playground, it is of course a simplified version of my app.
Basically I have a tabbed layout with two views which share a common datasource of items (in my app it's a sqlite db table); the first view displays items in a certain state whereas the other tab display the remaining items (in my example I've used the TODO list metaphor).
Each tab has a child state which I refer to as 2nd-level state (assuming level 0 is the abstract `tab` state. These two 2nd-level states are defined separately but share a common controller and template.
I cannot for the life of me understand why these two states aren't being navigated to when I click on a list item from either of the two lists (1st-level state views).
**NOTE:** In the ionic playground no error is thrown in the console, but I can't quite tell what is going on in terms of state URLs. But when I test my actual app (where the problem is the same) in a browser I can see the URL changing to `#/tab/tasks/xxxx` or `#/tab/completed/xxxx` but template is not loading. Upon googling I came across several SO questions:

1. [Ui-router URL changes, nested view not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30738779/1154866)
2. [In Angular ui-router nested state url changes,but template is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21424524/1154866)
3. [UI-Router: URL changes, but view is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32028180/1154866)
4. [Angular Router - Url changes but view does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28988055/1154866)
5. [URL changes but view does not hcange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28848827/1154866)
6. [Angular UI-Router : URL changed but view isn't loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30638397/1154866)

but the answers provided therein haven't worked for me (tried, as per the last one I listed, to add the `@` sign after the view name in the child states, but to no avail).

Kinda stuck, would really appreciate some input! Cheers.

Comment: Ionic routing with ion-nav has been painful for me. Do you get any error?

Comment: None. The URL changes but the template remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064219/1154866); I had previously tried simply appending the `@` character after the view name in nested states but it turns out the trick was to append `@tab`, where `tab` is the name of the top-level abstract state. I updated [my fiddle](http://play.ionic.io/app/575669414876) on ionic playground. Cheers to you all.